# How to list all installed applications with icon and check box in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application which can display a list of all `installed application` with their `Icon, Name & Check Box`, here follows my code

`activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/app_paackage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_app"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private PackageManager packageManager = null;
private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();

    new LoadApplications().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
    try {
        Intent intent = packageManager
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

        if (null != intent) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
    ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
    for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
        try {
            if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return applist;
}

private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.row, applist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(listadaptor);
        progress.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                "Loading application info...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
}
```

`ApplicationAdapter.java`

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;

public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.appsList = appsList;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (null == view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
    if (null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
        ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
    return view;
}
```

Problem is whenever I tick a `Check Box` and scroll other boxes in the scrolled window `Check Box` are being `selected`. Please help me to solve this riddle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this happens is because your views are being re-used but you do not reset the state of the checkbox in the `getView`.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
private Context context;
private PackageManager packageManager;
private ArrayList<Boolean> checkList = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

public ApplicationAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.appsList = appsList;
    packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {
        checkList.add(false);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
}

@Override
public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
    return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (null == view) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
    if (null != data) {
        TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
        TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_paackage);
        ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_app);
        checkBox.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position)); // set the tag so we can identify the correct row in the listener
        checkBox.setChecked(checkList.get(position); // set the status as we stored it        
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mListener); // set the listener

        appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
        packageName.setText(data.packageName);
        iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
    }
    return view;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener mListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {   
         checkList.set((Integer)buttonView.getTag(),isChecked); // get the tag so we know the row and store the status 
     }
};
}
```

Basically, have a arraylist which stores the status of each checkbox (that corresponds to your data). So for example: When you checkbox at position `1` is clicked, `checkList.get(1)` is `true`.

Since views are being re-used you need to store the state of each checkbox with respect to its position. i.e checkbox at position `x` is checked or not. Then when you do `getView()` for position `x` you use the stored state to set the correct checked value.

**Update** Initialize the checkList with `false` values.

Comment: Updated my answer. Since views are being re-used you need to store the state of each checkbox with respect to its position. i.e checkbox at position `x` is checked or not. Then when you do `getView()` for position `x` you use the stored state to set the correct checked value.

Comment: Exception, `Force Close`10-23 10:55:38.613: E/AndroidRuntime(2663):  at com.example.listallinstalledapps.ApplicationAdapter.getView(ApplicationAdapter.java:67)

Comment: What is the exception can you post full log? Might be some silly mistake we are making..

Comment: I see. I forgot to initialize the `checkList` with false values for each item. Initially for each item the checkbox will be unchecked.

Comment: can you please see the last line ` checkList.get((Integer)buttonView.getTag()) = isChecked; // get the tag so we know the row and store the status` why are you initializing like this, its a syntax erroe, is there any logic behind it @Amulya Khare

Comment: Nope, Issue remains, when I select `Check Box` and scroll they are being `un selected`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39794/discussion-between-chethan-shetty-and-amulya-khare)

Comment: hey when I check checkbox
I'm not able to store the package name of the position where I clicked
I'm getting som other value
improper value `HashSet<String> checkedItems = new HashSet<String>();if(isChecked){
      checkedItems.add(data.packageName);
     }else{
      checkedItems.remove(data.packageName);
     }`

Answer (score -1):

### you should maintain already visited items list in sqlite

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
                    {
                        if ( isChecked )
                        {
                            // perform logic
                            checkList.set((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); // get the tag so we know the row and store the status
                            int position = (int) buttonView.getTag();
                            Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            boolean result= help.insertContact(String.valueOf(position));
                            System.out.println(result);
                        }
    
                }
            });
        if (count == 0){
            count++;
            ids = new ArrayList<String>();
            ids = help.getAllCotacts();
            if (ids.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(checkList.set(Integer.parseInt(ids.get(i)),true));
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(ids.get(0)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No values in DB", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: First you have to pick the listview checkbox id and then insert into sqlite databse and the see  this code